# How to save tiff plot in ggplot without cropping the boundaries?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to save a plot in tiff format. I have this code below. I want to have the plot saved with the given aspect ratio, but when I save it portion of the figure gets cropped. Is there a way to fix this without increasing the width and size ?

```
filename = "myfile.tiff"
     ggsave(
     file = paste0(filename),
     plot = p,
     dpi = 150,
     width = 6,
     height = 6,
     units = "in"
   )
```

Comment: I can not recreate your problem when I tried  with `p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()`.

Comment: @Suren https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html

Comment: @Suren also you can try to recreate by reducing the width and height. In my case, I am having problem when I have 6in by 6 inches.

Comment: I did try. Still, it works as desired and I don't seem to have the problem you mention. I think you should try to give a reproducible example, maybe using the example I've given.